# unity (c#) in facebook, how to post to friends wall? how to get FBResult values?

Tags: android, facebook, post, unity-game-engine, feed

I succeed login and post my wall.

```
FB.API("me/photos", Facebook.HttpMethod.POST, Callback, wwwForm);// it works well.
FB.Feed("", "link", "link_name", ~~bulabula~~ );// it works well, too!
```

//////////////AND PLEASE SEE NEXT CODE. THIS IS PROBLEM.///////////////////

```
private string FriendSelectorTitle = "Share it with your friends!";
private string FriendSelectorMessage = "invite";
private string FriendSelectorFilters = "[\"all\"]";
private string FriendSelectorData = "{data}";
private string FriendSelectorExcludeIds = "";
private string FriendSelectorMax = "5";

private void CallAppRequestAsFriendSelector()
{
    // If there's a Max Recipients specified, include it
    int? maxRecipients = null;
    if (FriendSelectorMax != "")
    {
        try
        {
            maxRecipients = Int32.Parse(FriendSelectorMax);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            //status = e.Message;
            Debug.Log(e.Message);
        }
    }

    // include the exclude ids
    string[] excludeIds = (FriendSelectorExcludeIds == "") ? null : FriendSelectorExcludeIds.Split(',');
    List<object> FriendSelectorFiltersArr = null;
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(FriendSelectorFilters))
    {
        try
        {
            FriendSelectorFiltersArr = Facebook.MiniJSON.Json.Deserialize(FriendSelectorFilters) as List<object>;
        }
        catch
        {
            throw new Exception("JSON Parse error");
        }
    }

    FB.AppRequest(
        FriendSelectorMessage,
        null,
        FriendSelectorFiltersArr,
        excludeIds,
        maxRecipients,
        FriendSelectorData,
        FriendSelectorTitle,
        Callback
        );
}

void Callback(FBResult result)
{
    Debug.Log(result.Text);
}
```

/////////////////////////////////////////////////

it look like works well.

first, pop up friends selector dialog, 
and I clicked some friends, and click 'done' button.

it will call 'Callback' Funtion, and 
debug.log(FBResult.text); show follow like this.

```
{"request":"8939391818800568","to":["2446462595631736"],["189238719238719238"]}
```

but now, I don't know how to use these values. T_T

I think FB.feed(); is well done. So, 
I try to

```
for( int i=0; i<usernum; i++ )
{
   FB.feed( "id[user_index]" , bula~bula );
}
```

but failed.

becuase, fbresult.text is not string!!?

I try to split this string(fbresult.text), to get "to":["userid1 number"], ["userid2 number"]

but I failed and disappointed.

please someone help me.
Anybody who has a good idea???

I really want to send my message(pic or message) to friend's facebook wall.

Answer (score 2):

You can´t post to the wall of a friend anymore, since a very long time. In most (all?) cases this would be considered as spam, so they remove that possibility.

You can use the [Send Dialog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/send-dialog) to send something to a friend, for example.